# TGeocoder shows exclusively the address of the first marker

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Using the method shown below, markers are well drawn on the map. However, the `mapGeocoder.GeocodeReverse(coords);` always prints exclusively the address of the first marker, not the current one.

```
Procedure TfrmSijaliceMain.LSLocationChanged(Sender: TObject; const OldLocation,
  NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D);
var
  CurrentLocation   : TMapCoordinate;
  MarkerDescriptor  : TMapMarkerDescriptor;

  coords            : TLocationCoord2D;
begin
  coords.Latitude   := NewLocation.Latitude;
  coords.Longitude  := NewLocation.Longitude;
  CurrentLocation   := TMapCoordinate.Create(NewLocation.Latitude, NewLocation.Longitude);
  MapView.Location  := CurrentLocation;

  MarkerDescriptor  := TMapMarkerDescriptor.Create(CurrentLocation,
      Format('Lat: %2.6f, Lng: %2.6f', [NewLocation.Latitude, NewLocation.Longitude]));

  TBGMapMarkers.AddMarker(MapView.AddMarker(MarkerDescriptor));

  lblPosition.Text    := Format('Lat: %2.6f, Lng: %2.6f',
      [NewLocation.Latitude, NewLocation.Longitude]);

  if SwitchAddress.IsChecked then
  begin
      if Not Assigned(mapGeocoder) then
      begin

        if Assigned(TGeocoder.Current) then
          mapGeocoder := TGeocoder.Current.Create;

        if Assigned(mapGeocoder) then
          mapGeocoder.OnGeocodeReverse := OnGeocodeReverseEventMap;

      end;

      if Assigned(mapGeocoder) and not mapGeocoder.Geocoding then
        mapGeocoder.GeocodeReverse(coords);
  end;
end;
```

The code is used exclusively on Android, and the Delphi version is 10.4.2.

(added)

```
procedure TfrmSijaliceMain.OnGeocodeReverseEventMap(const Address: TCivicAddress);
begin
  LastLocationGeocode   := Address;

  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Clear;
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('AdminArea: ' + Address.AdminArea);
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('Thoroughfare: ' + UpperCase(Address.Thoroughfare));
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('FeatureName: ' + UpperCase(Address.FeatureName));
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('PostalCode: ' + Address.PostalCode);
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('SubLocality: ' + UpperCase(Address.SubLocality));
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('Locality: ' + UpperCase(Address.Locality));
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('SubAdminArea: ' + Address.SubAdminArea);
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('CountryCode: ' + Address.CountryCode);
  mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Add('CountryName: ' + UpperCase(Address.CountryName));
end;
```

(added)

TBGMapMarkers is class that contains list of markers.

```
type
  TBGMapMarkers = class
  private
    class var FBGMapMarkers   : TBGMapMarkers;
    FMarkers  : TList<TMapMarker>;
    FMaxCount: Integer;
    class function GetMaxCount: Integer; static;
    class procedure SetMaxCount(const Value: Integer); static;
    class function GetMarkerCount: Integer; static;
    class function GetMarker(index: integer): TMapMarker; static;
    class procedure SetMarker(index: integer; const Value: TMapMarker); static;
  protected
    constructor Create;
  public
    class function Instance: TBGMapMarkers;
    class procedure AddMarker(Marker: TMapMarker);


    destructor Destroy; override;
    class property MaxCount: Integer read GetMaxCount write SetMaxCount;
    class property MarkerCount: Integer read GetMarkerCount;
    class property Marker[index: integer]: TMapMarker read GetMarker write SetMarker;
  end;

implementation

{ TBGMapMarkers }

class procedure TBGMapMarkers.AddMarker(Marker: TMapMarker);
begin
  if FBGMapMarkers = nil then
    FBGMapMarkers := TBGMapMarkers.Create;

  if FMarkers.Count = FMaxCount then
  begin
    FMarkers[0].Remove;
    FMarkers.Delete(0);
  end;

  FMarkers.Add(Marker);
end;

constructor TBGMapMarkers.Create;
begin
  inherited;

  FMarkers    := TList<TMapMarker>.Create;
  FMaxCount   := 10;
end;

destructor TBGMapMarkers.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FMarkers) then
  begin
    while FMarkers.Count > 0 do
      FMarkers[0].Free;

    FMarkers.Free;
  end;

  inherited;
end;

class function TBGMapMarkers.GetMarker(index: integer): TMapMarker;
begin
  if FBGMapMarkers = nil then
    FBGMapMarkers := TBGMapMarkers.Create;

  Result    := FMarkers[index];
end;

class function TBGMapMarkers.GetMarkerCount: Integer;
begin
  if FBGMapMarkers = nil then
    FBGMapMarkers := TBGMapMarkers.Create;

  Result    := FMarkers.Count;
end;

class function TBGMapMarkers.GetMaxCount: Integer;
begin
  if FBGMapMarkers = nil then
    FBGMapMarkers := TBGMapMarkers.Create;

  Result    := FBGMapMarkers.FMaxCount;
end;

class function TBGMapMarkers.Instance: TBGMapMarkers;
begin
  if FBGMapMarkers = nil then
    FBGMapMarkers   := TBGMapMarkers.Create;

  Result    := FBGMapMarkers;
end;

class procedure TBGMapMarkers.SetMarker(index: integer;
  const Value: TMapMarker);
begin
  if FBGMapMarkers = nil then
    FBGMapMarkers := TBGMapMarkers.Create;

  FMarkers[index]   := Value;
end;

class procedure TBGMapMarkers.SetMaxCount(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if FBGMapMarkers = nil then
    FBGMapMarkers   := TBGMapMarkers.Create;

  FBGMapMarkers.FMaxCount   := Value;
end;
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance
Bojan

Comment: What is **TBGMapMarkers**?  Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You said "*GeocodeReverse(coords); always prints exclusively the address of the first marker*". `GeocodeReverse` doesn't print anything, it request the address matching the specified coordinates and call the `OnGeocodeReverse` event that you don't show.

Comment: Did you check that `OnGeocodeReverseEventMap` is called only once? Replace `mmoLastMarkerAddress.Lines.Clear;` line by an empty line so that you are sure to see everything.

Comment: I did it. Only the parameters of the first marker are shown in the list, by repetition. I can take screenshots. I'll try an older version of Delphi. I will try with the older version of Delphi, because I checked the behaviour on Android 8, 9 and 11.

Comment: Is the second marker address really different than the first one? Maybe both refer to the same address? Try manually adding two markers at two street edges and then GeocodeReverse each (by geographic coordinates) to see what happens.

Comment: Yes, They are different. I also walked different streets. I walked a few miles. Of course I had mobile data turned on, otherwise the app would have closed.